# Qpython Plyer GPS - Crash on call of gps.start() method

Tags: android, python, gps, kivy, qpython

My goal is to know the geographic coordinates of my Nexus 5 (*Andrid 5.1.1*) using the python module **Plyer**(*Version 1.2.4*).

So I installed the interpreter **QPython2.7**(*Version 1.0.6*) on my smartphone and I wrote the following code inspired by the example on Plyer documentation https://plyer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#plyer.facades.GPS .
Qpyton2.7 installation include **Kivy** module(*Version 1.8.0*) that I used in my code.

**What I expect the program do:**

When I press the button the program'll start the location updates when I press it again the program'll stop the updates.
When the program updates the location it'll call loc() method to update the button text value with the current location.

**What the program really do:**

It crashes on gps.start() call.

**Notes:**

The program doesn't crash on gps.configure() previous call.
The method vibrator.vibrate() of Plyer module works fine!

**Error reported:**

...

File "jnius_export_class.pxi", line 562, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.**call** (jnius/jnius.c:17724)
   File "jnius_export_class.pxi", line 656, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_method (jnius/jnius.c:18722)
   File "jnius_utils.pxi", line 43, in jnius.jnius.check_exception (jnius/jnius.c:3175)
jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occured

**THE CODE:**

```
#qpy:kivy

from plyer import vibrator
from plyer import gps
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.locbutton = Button(text='START', on_press=self.start_stop)
        return self.locbutton

    def on_start(self):
        gps.configure(on_location=self.loc)

    def loc(self, **kwargs):
        self.locbutton.text = 'lat:{lat},lon:{lon}'.format(**kwargs)

    def start_stop(self, instance):
        if self.locbutton.text == 'START':
            #self.locbutton.text = 'STOP'
            gps.start()
        else:
            gps.stop()
            self.locbutton.text = 'START'
        vibrator.vibrate(0.01)

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Could this have something to do with permissions?

Comment: It could be, googling on internet I found that the permissions can compromise the Plyer operation but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I checked right now the QPython authorizations in the Info App, it seems to have access to localization system!

Comment: I ran the program with **Kivy Launcher** and everything works fine!
I don't know why QPython fails the execution.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not run because of the method call bes gps plyer passing as parameters on_location = its function example:

```
from plyer import gps
from kivy.app import App
from import kivy.uix.button Button

class mi_app(App):
    def buscar_coord (self, **kwargs):
        info = Kwargs.items()
        ## Decodificas the json
        print str(info)
    def gps_activar(self, ins):
        self.buscar_coord()
    def build(self):
        gps.configure (on_location = self.buscar_coord)
        ## we call start method
        gps.start ()
        return Button(text = "TEST_GPS" on_release = self.gps_activar)

mi_app().run()
```

Comment: jeyfrin, Thanks for your answer, but please be sure to always use the code formatting blocks to make your code readable to other users.